# XY Bar Graph datanot Corresponding matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to create a Bar Graph based on 2 Lists that I am dragging from a CSV file.

these are the two lists defined as X and Y

```
[42127L, 42129L, 44161L, 44166L, 44167L, 44168L, 44169L, 44170L]
[21.873210633899998, 19.125503355699998, 19.9757477769, 20.5028595637, 20.4502863092, 18.4269712278, 20.4741833509, 19.2441994027]
```

however, the X Values don't appear to be lining up.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("N:\\Wild_Pig_Project\\\Mean_temp.csv", names = ['Device_ID', 'Mean'])

y = df.Mean.tolist()
x = df.Device_ID.tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 50
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.set_yticklabels(y)
ax.bar(x, y, width, color='Red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to modify your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['42127L', '42129L', '44161L', '44166L', '44167L', '44168L', '44169L', '44170L']
y = [21.873210633899998, 19.125503355699998, 19.9757477769, 20.5028595637, 20.4502863092, 18.4269712278, 20.4741833509, 19.2441994027]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar([idx for idx in range(len(x))], y, color='Red')
ax.set_xticks([idx+0.5 for idx in range(len(x))])
ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=35, ha='right', size=10)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The key points are:

1. You must set the xticks(yticks) for the positions of your xtick(ytick) labels.
2. The first argument of 'bar()' is the position of each bar.

BTW, I am not quite sure why you want to use customized labels of your yticks I guess you want to show a comparison of processing time btw different devices. 
This should give you a reasonable result.

Comment: Both of these answers make sense!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the xticks themselves to `x` as well as the xticklabels. However, your `x` data is not evenly spaced and will produce a graph with bars bunched very close together (similar to what is shown in your screenshot).

A solution can be to create an evenly spaced array and, plot a bar chart using this and then setting the tick labels to `x`.

An example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [42127, 42129, 44161, 44166, 44167, 44168, 44169, 44170]
y = [21.873210633899998, 19.125503355699998, 19.9757477769, 20.5028595637, 20.4502863092, 18.4269712278, 20.4741833509, 19.2441994027]
ticks = np.arange(1,9,1) # can replace 9 with len(y) to be a more general solution

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.5

ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)  
ax.set_yticklabels(y)

ax.bar(ticks, y, width, color='Red')

plt.show()
```

Which produces the following figure:

[image]